# BackboneJS, RequireJS App module accessible from whole project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, requirejs

In the backbone-on-rails gem everything is loaded into one 'super-class'

```
window.MyApp =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}   

  initialize: ->
    # start code here
```

And then all classes are created by

```
users = new MyApp.Collections.Users()
```

But the important thing is that I can set a variable up to be an attribute on that top-level class and then access it from anywhere.

```
MyApp.router = new MyApp.Routers.AppRouter()

# so later in a view I can call 
MyApp.router.navigate(...)
```

So now I'm making a simple JS app that I don't need Rails for and I've been using RequireJS to handle everything that the RoR assets pipeline does so wonderfully. That was a bit of a struggle to begin with but I've worked all that out.

The real problem I'm having is that I really want that 'top-level' class so I can make a model accessible throughout my app (mostly to every view). But I'm not able to do this.

```
require.config
  paths:
    jquery: '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min'
    underscore: 'vendor/underscore.min'
    backbone: 'vendor/backbone.min'
    templates: '../templates'

 require ['app'], (App) ->
   # I tried something like this, but window.MapApp still is inaccessible
   window.MapApp = App
   MapApp.initialize()
```

I really want to be able to set App.user = new User(...) and also App.router = new Router(...)

Thanks for sticking with me through this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your namespace in a separate module, then include that module as needed:

app:

```
define (require) ->
  app = {}
  app.Models = {}
  app.Collections = {}
  app.Views = {}
  app.Router = {}
  return app
```

main:

```
require.config
  ...
require [
  'app'  
  'backbone'
  'router'    
], (MyApp, Backbone, AppRouter) ->
  MyApp.Router = new AppRouter
  Backbone.history.start();
  MyApp.Router.navigate ...
```

Here's a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Hc7ed/

I should add that (especially if you're starting from scratch) you don't need to use a namespace when using Require.js; those modules don't pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is modify the structure proposed by the tutorial [here](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) to pass around the application object to the `initialize` function of the modules. For instance the `router.js` file could have this function:

```
var initialize = function (app) {
    app.Routers = app.Routers || {};
    app.Routers.AppRouter = AppRouter;

    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    app.router = app_router;
    [...]
};
```

Also, you mention that this does not work:

```
window.MapApp = App
```

If the file which contains the `"app"` module depends on files that contain your router and views, etc., then it is *necessarily* the case that when the files that implement your router and views load and their factories (the callback passed to their `define` calls) are executed `window.MapApp = App` has not **yet** been executed because this statement *cannot* execute until all modules `"app"` depends on have loaded and their factories have been called.